# Object Normals to follow Rig

Tags: scripting, drivers, shader-nodes, vertex-weights, toon-shading

I've been searching far and wide for this solution lol. Does anyone know how to make object normal maps connect and follow a rig 'proportionately'? My example here shows it's possible but it affects the whole map [image: text]

video (clearer) version of texture prop driven to jaw rig: [LINK](https://www.flickr.com/photos/195822106@N08/52113506983/in/dateposted-public/)

Would like to know of a way to pinpoint what influences where. I got things rolling thanks to this video (27:52): [LINK](https://youtu.be/sQW2wqltB0A?t=1672)) but still stuck in the same scenario on how to proceed. It's hard for me to picture in my head on what to do.

I looked at this and thought it was cool but have no clue if I'm warm or cold in the idea to link painted portions (weight or vertex color, or one into either) to prop driver [LINK](https://blog.michelanders.nl/2015/02/transfer-vertex-weights-to-vertex_28.html). But then I'm stuck: How would I set anything of the sorts up? With nodes? With certain sections in Blender I'm unaware of? Scripts? Is this the actual way to do it?

My apologies for sounding too newbie. But if there's a solution, it can reduce a lot of headaches for the BNPR (Blender NPR) community lol. Object normals don't break as bad as tangent normals which do work regardless with a rig or not.

Comment: Basically, you'd need an Object for every major deform bone in the mesh, and to mix between them with their vertex weights. This is technically possible in GN, but hard to setup and who knows about performance. And not too hard to setup in python, but performance would be crap. This sort of thing should become convenient if we get Bone access and For loops in Geometry Nodes.